# Too much power for 1-2 power outlets in my room?

Tags: power-management

I live in the USA, I am curious about plugging in too many computer items into 1 to 2 power plugin outlets.

Most power outlets have 2 plugins, some have 4 and more though.  Many people will plug in a power strib/bar into 1 of these outlets so that they can plugin even more items.

So if I have 2 plugins near my computer, would it be bad to plugin;

- My PC
- 3-4 monitors
- Stereo amp for PC sound
- Lamp
- External drives
- Other similar items

Answer (score 5):

Your power budget is 1875 watts (assuming 15 A at 125 V) for one outlet.

Your PC's power supply is probably rated at about 400 watts, but will typically use far less.

Even then a conservative budget could be:

```
  Device                      Power [W]
  -------------------------------------------
  PC                          400
  4 monitors at 50 W          200
  Stereo                       20
  2 Lamps at 100 W            200
  4 External drives at 20 W    80
  other similar items         200
  -------------------------------------------
  Total                      1100
```

So you are far from the limit.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the amperage of the circuit more then the number of outlets. Go the the breaker panel and figure out which breaker controls that circuit and note the amperage. Then total the amperage of all devices.

Answer (score 1):

If Your home power circuit is setup correctly fuse should work and protect You in case of over current.

If You don't trust Your fuses You have to calculate how much current will You use.

It's some times is given on the device or in manual but in other case the math is simple:

> I=P/120V
>   (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_power)

where I is current and P is device Power. As r0ca said current per outlet shouldn't be greater then 15A

Answer (score 1):

The "Kill A Watt" from P3 is handy (and cheap ~$20) for checking how much current your equipment is drawing in various conditions.  You can use it on your equipment during actual use and have a pretty good idea how close to 15A you are coming on the circuit for your outlets.

BTW, I have two desktops, a laser printer, and a few other pieces all running on the same circuit.  This runs fine (but it pushes it a little when the laser is actually printing).

Answer (score 0):

I live in Canada, which is the same electrical standard, and here, the standard is 120V and 15A per outlets. So normally, for your stuff, I would use 2 set of 2 outlets. That should fit perfectly since a monitor takes 50-60W (Most models).

So 2 outlets for monitors and 2 others for the rest! It's not bad to take a bit more but in a room, sometimes it's hard to have 2 or 3 sets of outlet.